# Convergence of newton's method with cube roots

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson

How can you prove that Newton's method for estimating the cube root converges when $x_0$ is not $0$? Where sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ can be defined with the relation $x_{n+1} = \frac{2}{3}x_n + \frac{1}{3}\frac{z}{x_n^2} $.

I tried to figure out a way to write this as another formula to be proved by induction that it is monotonic and bounded, but I have no idea how to do that. I tried writing out the terms, and cannot figure out a formula for that.

Edit: z is the term of which you are finding the cube root.

Comment: Are you taking initial conditions with the same sign as $z$? (I don't think this matters, but the details are harder if the signs are different.)

Comment: I'd like to know for all cases, where signs are the same and signs are different.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: suppose $z \neq 0$, $r=z^{1/3}$. Let $g(x)=x-\frac{x^3-z}{3x^2}$. We have two cases:

If $x>r$ then $x>g(x)>r$. This implies the recursive sequence $g^n(x)$ is bounded and monotone, so it is convergent. The limit of a recursive sequence defined by a continuous mapping must be a fixed point of the mapping, and the only fixed point of $g$ is $r$.

If $x<r$ then it is true that $x<g(x)$ (so that you move toward the root). But in general it is not true that $g(x)<r$, so the sequence is no longer guaranteed to be monotone. So the error may not go to zero monotonically, either. As a workaround, you can show that eventually $g^n(x)>r$, at which point the previous case applies.

To make this work out, you will need to additionally assume that $g^n(x)$ is never *exactly* zero, which rules out a countable set of initial values. (Thankfully, all of these points, except for $0$ itself, have the opposite sign from $r$, so there is no reason you should ever encounter them.)

Comment: How did you get the formula for g(x)?

Comment: @LoRan $g$ is just the function that you iterate for Newton's method for cube roots. In other words Newton's method amounts to $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$. It is the same as you wrote, just "unsimplified" (and I think you are better off leaving it that way, at least for analytical purposes).

Comment: If $z>0$ and  $0<x<z^{1/3}$ then $g(x)>z^{1/3}.$

Comment: @user254665 Thank you, that means I can combine those cases.